# Create a new structure with values

Tags: c, struct

My program needs to get an entry and put it in a linked list, and indeed the first entry enters properly but once the second entry enters all the time the next of struct is initialized at the same entry full times. How do I make it insert a value every time in spelling_suggestion-> originalWord and in the next iteration it will enter a new value next

```
typedef struct SpellingSuggestion SpellingSuggestion;

struct SpellingSuggestion {
    char* originalWord;
    LinkedList* suggestions;
    SpellingSuggestion* next;
};
    SpellingSuggestion* spelling_suggestion = (SpellingSuggestion*)malloc(sizeof(SpellingSuggestion));
    
strcpy(strTemp, getWord(counter, i, text));
spelling_suggestion->originalWord = strTemp;
spelling_suggestion->next = NULL;
SpellingSuggestion* temp, * new_elem;
new_elem = strTemp;
if (spelling_suggestion == NULL)
    return new_elem;
for (temp = spelling_suggestion; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next);
    spelling_suggestion->next = temp;
```

getWord(counter, i, text) return string name

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The `for` loop always and only fills `spelling_suggestion->next` ; isn't it weird ?

Comment: The posted code is incomplete so it's hard to help... Update the question and show all relevant code.